# How to add array

Tags: functions, users, redirect, user-roles, wp-redirect

I have this following code,

```
if ('plugins.php' === $pagenow ||'update-core.php' === $pagenow ) {   
   // wp_safe_redirect( home_url() ); 
 // Now check the current user
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( $user->user_login == 'Remo' ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() );
    exit();
}
```

The above code redirects the user named `Remo` to the home page whenever he tries to access the update page in dashboard.

So, now I want to add another user named 'Sam'.

How can I add sam using array.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `$users = array( 'Remo', 'Sam' ); if ( in_array( $user->login, $users) ) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need array to do this. The following code will be worked. You have to just add other username also inside if condition with `or` operation.

```
if ('plugins.php' === $pagenow ||'update-core.php' === $pagenow ) {   
   // wp_safe_redirect( home_url() ); 
 // Now check the current user
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( $user->user_login == 'Remo' || $user->user_login == 'Sam') {
    wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() );
    exit();
}
```

If you want to use array you can add users to array and then you can use `in_array` function to check it.

```
if ('plugins.php' === $pagenow ||'update-core.php' === $pagenow ) {   
   // wp_safe_redirect( home_url() ); 
 // Now check the current user
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$users = array("Remo", "Sam");

if ( in_array($user->user_login, $users)) {
    wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() );
    exit();
}
```